# Error de Sintaxis en Funcion Filter de Python

Tags: python, sintaxis, filtro

Estoy aprendiendo Python por mi cuenta, y al utilizar la función `filter`
en el siguiente código me aparece un error de sintaxis pero no logro identificar:

```
class Empleado:

    def__init__(self, nombre, cargo, salario):

        self.nombre=nombre
        
        self.cargo=cargo
        
        self.salario=salario


    def__str__(self):

        return"{} que trabaja como {} tiene un salario de {} $ MEX".format(self.nombre, self.cargo, self.salario)


listaEmpleados=[
Empleado("Carlos", "Director", 75000),
Empleado("Juan", "CEO", 95000),
Empleado("Nayeli", "Analista", 30000),
Empleado("Nicte", "Asistente", 25000),
]

salarios_altos=filter(lambda empleado:empleado.salario>50000, listaEmpleados)

for empleado_salario in salarios_altos:
    print(empleado_salario)
```

Y de error me aparece esto, y no entiendo bien el por qué?:

```
  File "Funcion_Filter.py", line 3
    def__init__(self, nombre, cargo, salario):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

No veo bien, pero la declaración de la función no está separada del método, o sea `def espacio __init__`. Ese espacio no lo veo e igual en la otra.

```
def __init__etc
```

Ya se que van a patalear, lo quise poner como comentario y nunca pude.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. También tiene el mismo problema con la definición de `__str__`.  Nadie va a a patalear.

Comment: Ya hice tal cual me comentaron, quedo asi:  def __str__(self):                  Pero no queda, me sale este error:          File "Funcion_Filter.py", line 12
    def __str__(self):
                     ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level        
Disculpen si soy molesto, aun soy principiante pero estoy tratando de entender todos los errores pero no me queda muy claro aqui. Gracias

Comment: antes de trabajar con clases deberías aprender lo fundamental de python que es la indentación, el error te lo dice, de la forma simple, después de ":" la línea siguiente debe estar a 4 espacios con relación a la anterior, parece que hay más en este caso